# Unable to access over a network using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, net.tcp

I have a WCF self-hosted service in a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application. I am going to be using it so a hand-held mobile device can interact with the application at a basic level.

I have enabled basicHttp (`http://localhost:8080/tagservice/basic`), NetTCP (`net.tcp://localhost:8888/tagservice`), and basicHttpMex as endpoints.

For testing purposes, I have setup a virtual machine on the network (and repeated these on a physical machine as well).

These endpoints all work on the local machine where the service is hosted.

However when running the WCFTestClient on remote machines I get mixed results.

1. Using the above endpoints, I can connect to the service and see the service contracts, proving the mex (IMetadataExhange) works. But I cannot use either http or net.tcp. I get the error message

> Could not connect to http://localhost:8080/tagservice/basic. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080.
>
> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8888/tagservice. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0014400. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888.

2. When changing localhost to the real IP address in the app.config on the host, in this case 192.168.0.61. Basic HTTP works. However net.icp fails with

   "The server has rejected the client credentials."

My two questions are:

1. Why is the net.tcp failing? I am not given a choice to enter credentials as far as I can tell.
2. Given the IP address can change, how can I get the app.config to use the IP address it is assigned by the DHCP server? As once this software moves from development to production environment the IP address cannot be hardcoded as it will change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build and configure the client binding at runtime, so you can programmatically set the URL based on the machine information

Something like this should work

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
int port = 8080;
Uri serviceUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}", hostName, port.ToString()));


EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
```

Then you just attach that endpoint to your client and it should all hook up.

Comment: This sounds more like the solution I am looking for, so the end point is grammatically created. I have only used the app.config previously to setup endpoints.

Comment: Almost everything in WCF config can be done programmatically.  If you run into trouble, please post the <client> section of your web.config and I can give example of how to do it in code

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `localhost` to your hostname (if IP address is dynamic) or IP address(if static) and recompile your client.

Comment: In which case, can I make the hostname configurable? The hostname of the client machine is not known in advance, so I cannot hardcode the hostname in the app.config. There is the possibility they may switch machine at will and as such the hostname would likely change.

Comment: app.config is config and loaded on strartup. Its not hardcode.

Comment: Very true, I did forget about that. I guess an installer program could write in the hostname in the app.config file. Any suggestions on the net.tcp program?